# How to save line breaks in database

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using typeorm to management my databse with nestjs framework on server and vuejs on client side,

in settings i must provide a large text and i must to save linebreaks (`\n`) in database,

my code:

vue textarea

```
<b-form-textarea 
       style="white-space: pre-line"
       v-model="projectShortDesc"
       class="mt-2 description-input"></b-form-textarea>
```

then i send this data from `v-model="projectShortDesc"` to my server,

```
  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 150,
    nullable: true
  })
  shortDescription: string;
```

and save like this:

```
project.shortDescription = descFromVue;
await this.conn.getRepository(Project).save(project);
```

can someone tell me how to save in database '\n' when i enter `enter` in description?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @lsouza mysql////

Answer (score 0):

To add linebreaks in mysql db ,You need to append /n whenever the user hits on enter key in the text box.I think this will help you

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <b-form-textarea 
       style="white-space: pre-line"
       v-model="projectShortDesc"
       class="mt-2 description-input"
        v-on:keyup.enter="onEnter">
      </b-form-textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: "App",
 methods: {
  onEnter() {
    this.projectShortDesc.apend('/n')
    },
 },
};
</script>
```